# I can't get phpseclib to work

Tags: php, phpseclib

### What I want to do

I want to `upload`/`download` a file via `sftp` using `php`. 
The `phpseclib-library` looks very promising.

### What I already did

I changed my conposer.json to:

```
{
    "require": {
        "nicolab/php-ftp-client":"*",
        "php-curl-class/php-curl-class":"*",
        "phpseclib/phpseclib":"*"
    }
}
```

Then i updated my directory. Composer installed the library in the vendor folder.

### The Problem

The problem is that I am unable to create a new `SFTP-Object`.

```
Fatal error: Class 'SFTP' not found in...
```

I also tried `NET_SFTP` as classname but this didn't work also. 
One thing I dont understand is why [on](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/sftp/examples.html#stat), it states that the classname is `NET_SFTP` when in the source its clearly called `SFTP`.

Also autoload seems not to work.

I added `echo "testline";` to the library to see if the file is loaded. Nothing happens if I use the autoloading. if i manually include the file, `"testline"` is printed but the class is still not found.

### My Code

Example one

```
<?php
include '/vendor/autoload.php';

$sftp = new SFTP('domain');
if (!$sftp->login('user', 'pass')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
```

-> no echo

Example two:

```
<?php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib/phpseclib');

include('Net/SSH2.php');

include('Net/SFTP.php');

$sftp = new SFTP('www.domain.tld');
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
```

-> echo

In both examples it cant find the class.

Comment: Just wanted to note for phpseclib 3.0, its `use phpseclib3\Net\SFTP;`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> One thing I dont understand is why on http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/sftp/examples.html#stat it states that the classname is NET_SFTP when in the source its clearly called SFTP.

The website is documenting the 1.0 branch. The 2.0 branch has a similar API but it is not identical. In particular, it is namespaced whereas the 1.0 branch isn't.

To modify your first example...

```
<?php
include '/vendor/autoload.php';

$sftp = new \phpseclib\Net\SFTP('domain');
if (!$sftp->login('user', 'pass')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
```

The master branch's API is subject to change. Only 1.0 and 2.0 have fixed API's. As such I think an update to your composer.json would also be appropriate. ie. do `"phpseclib/phpseclib": "~2.0"` instead of `*`.